# Expand the size of / partition with unallocated space

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a 1TB disk and only partitioned 10Gib for my / directory and now I want to add the remaining .9Tib or so to that partition. It is currently sitting as unallocated space. Attached is a picture of my GParted screen so you can see how the table is partitioned. I have GParted launched as an ISO so that the main directories are unmounted, but I still have no luck resizing.

[image]

Comment: To make it easy, I would just partition the unallocated space into about 25GB /, and what amount you want for /home, then install in the new partitions.  You can then copy what you want into new home from old home.  Both of your partitions are almost full and trying to move them around would be difficult.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You're missing a crucial detail here: What happens when you try to resize? If there is an error, you need to include it in full. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: `/` is on sda2, right? Just to be clear

Comment: Most have ESP as first partition, so not in way and swap last for same reason. But new installs now use swap file, so swap partition not really required, but will be used. Your swap is small, but if lots of RAM, probably does not matter. If newer install, then a reinstall to reoriganize may be worthwhile. Also be sure to back up. Especially /home, maybe /etc if you edited any system configuration files and export list of installed apps, if you added many to make it easy to restore them. App data will be in /home.

Answer (score 0):

You are still using the disk!

Stop using the swap space on `/dev/sda1`, see `man swapoff`.

`gparted` will not alter a disk's partition table if ANY of the disk's partitions is in use.

Comment: The "key" icon next to `/dev/sda1` entry shows the swap partition was grabbed by `swapon -a` at system boot..OP MUST `swapoff`.